# SQL Server Import/Export changes datetime2 to smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server, export

I'm exporting data from SQL Server 2014 to a new database on a 2008 R2 server. The date columns in the source DB are all `datetime2`, but the wizard changes those mappings to `smalldatetime` and the export therefore fails. There are a lot of columns and tables in this DB, so going through every single table to edit the mappings is rather time-consuming. Is there a way to fix this so the mappings actually work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Close import / export wizard

```
Modify in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\MappingFiles\MSSQLToSSIS10.XML 
the latest section:
smalldatetime; 
<dtm:DataTypeName>DT_DBTIMESTAMP into DT_DBTIMESTAMP2.
```

Start wizard and try again your selections from the start
Works perfectly for me :-)